# Search a value and get other values

Tags: php

I have for example this JSON:

```
    {
    "status": "OK",
    "response": {
        "1": {
            "name": "Personal Information",
            "fields": {
                "1": {
                    "name": "About Me",
                    "value": ""
                },
                "4": {
                    "name": "Discord name",
                    "value": "TestAccount#1012"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a chance that for example I search to **Discord name** and I get **TestAccount#1012**?

Because the ID numbers or what called them will change sometimes "probably". 
(I am trying to easier way to read my forum rest api)

UPDATE:
It is my current code:

```
<?php {
if ( $_GET ) //Make sure it is a post request.
{
    if ( isset( $_GET[ "forum" ] ) && isset( $_GET[ "api" ] ) && isset( $_GET[ "username" ] ) ) //Make sure username and serial are provided.
    {
        $communityUrl = $_GET[ "forum" ];
        $apiKey = $_GET[ "api" ];


        $curl = curl_init( $communityUrl . 'api/index.php?/core/members&name=' . $_GET[ "username" ] );
        curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
            CURLOPT_USERPWD => "{$apiKey}:"
        ) );
        $response = curl_exec( $curl );
        header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
        if ( $response === false ) {
            // Website down so result is this
            $jsonanswer = array(
                "status" => 'FAILED',
                "response" => 'Test1'
            );
            echo json_encode( $jsonanswer, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
        } else {
            $requestjson = json_decode( $response, true );
            $checkuser = $requestjson[ 'results' ];
            switch ( json_last_error() ) {
                case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
                    // Check if there is a member
                    if ( empty( $checkuser ) ) {
                        $jsonanswer = array(
                            "status" => 'NOTFOUND',
                            "response" => 'Test2' 
                        );
                        echo json_encode( $jsonanswer, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
                    } else {
                        $jsonanswer = array(
                                    "status" => 'OK',
                                    "response" => $requestjson[ 'results' ][ 0 ][ 'customFields' ]
                                );
                                echo json_encode( $jsonanswer, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );

                    }
                    break;
                case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
                    // Maximum stack depth exceeded
                    $jsonanswer = array(
                        "status" => 'FAILED',
                        "response" => 'Test3'
                    );
                    echo json_encode( $jsonanswer, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
                    break;
                case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
                    // Underflow or the modes mismatch
                    $jsonanswer = array(
                        "status" => 'FAILED',
                        "response" => 'Test 4'
                    );
                    echo json_encode( $jsonanswer, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
                    break;
                case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
                    // Unexpected control character found
                    $jsonanswer = array(
                        "status" => 'FAILED',
                        "response" => 'Test 5'
                    );
                    echo json_encode( $jsonanswer, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
                    break;
                case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
                    // Syntax error, malformed JSON
                    $jsonanswer = array(
                        "status" => 'FAILED',
                        "response" => 'Test 6'
                    );
                    echo json_encode( $jsonanswer, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
                    break;
                case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
                    // Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
                    $jsonanswer = array(
                        "status" => 'FAILED',
                        "response" => 'Test 7'
                    );
                    echo json_encode( $jsonanswer, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
                    break;
                default:
                    // Unknown error
                    $jsonanswer = array(
                        "status" => 'FAILED',
                        "response" => 'Test 8'
                    );
                    echo json_encode( $jsonanswer, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
                    break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        die( "Access Denied!" ); //Not a post request. Display Access Denied and exit.
    }

} else {
    die( "Access Denied!" ); //Not a post request. Display Access Denied and exit.
}
```

}

Currently I am requesting the customfield but after I don't know how to filter that I get the value if I search to **Discord name**.

Comment: You need to request json format data while using rest api.

Comment: ___Is there a chance that for example I search to Discord name and I get TestAccount#1012?___ YES, but only if your code is wrong

Comment: You could iterate over each object and check it's name then pull the value. https://3v4l.org/51q0l  Not sure what the "customFields" are, your example didnt have that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fun way if the `name` values are unique:

```
$name = 'Discord name';

echo array_column(current(json_decode($json, true)['response'])['fields'],
                  'value', 'name')[$name];
```

If you've already decoded the JSON:

```
echo array_column(current($array['response'])['fields'], 'value', 'name')[$name];
```

This is extracting a new array using `name` as the key and `value` as the value and accessing the key `$name`.